# Is it possible to know the size of PDF image placeholder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdfsharp

I'd like to resize PDF's images according to their placeholder size. I'm aware of how to iterate through PDF doc and how to retrieve each image and its size. But I can only get the original size of image (using "/Width" and "/Height" xObject key). The size of placeholder that an image will be placed in is still unknown.

Comment: What do you mean by image *placeholder*?

Comment: @mkl there is PDF template that has several PictureBoxes that are editable by DevExpress Report Designer. During editing I can specify PictureBox resolution. But exact image that will be placed into PictureBox will be defined in runtime and the resolution of the image can be different. I'd like to resize image resolution according to the resolution of bordered area that the image will be placed into. Aside that I can only work with rendered PDF (similar to how Adobe PDF Compression works)

Comment: The format PDF does not know something like "PictureBoxes" or *image placeholders* in general. Thus, you're dealing with a custom PDF extension by DevExpress Report Designer. To support this "PictureBox" extension, therefore, you have to ask them for a specification. Of course you can also try reverse engineering their PDFs but that opens the doors of misinterpretation...

Comment: adobe pdf has a picture box that can be filled in the adobe acrobat reader by clicking the placeholder.